# How to order by with result set?

Tags: java, sql

I want to make a leaderboard with SQL.
So I have to ORDER BY with `kills` in my case to get the results sorted.

But with the result set, the order is wrong.

```java
HashMap<String, Integer> player_list = new HashMap<>();
preparedStatement = this.pvpBox.getDtb().getConnection().prepareStatement(
    "SELECT player_name, kills FROM players ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 10");
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    player_list.put(resultSet.getString("player_name"), resultSet.getInt("kills"));
}
```

No error message.

I've already tried in the "SQL" section of PHPMyAdmin and I'm getting the expected result..

***Table example :***

```
    player_name     kills
    player1         40
    player2         20
    player3         50
    player4         10
    player5         30
```

***Actual result :***

```
    player_name     kills
    player5         30
    player1         40
    player4         10
    player2         20
    player3         50
```

***Expected result :***

```
    player_name     kills
    player3         50
    player1         40
    player5         30
    player2         20
    player4         10
```

I'm using Java 8 and Apache 2.

**Solution : Use the LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap (hashmap does not have any order).**

Comment: What `List` implementation are you using? It may not track insertion order.

Comment: try SELECT player_name, kills FROM players ORDER BY kills DESC without the limit. not sure if its gonna help but worth a try i guess

Comment: @Alan the limit should not interfere with this.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the results inside of the while loop to see if they are corrent? As @Andronicus pointed out, it could be cause by incorrect `List` implementation

Comment: @lealceldeiro i know. but who knows maybe its one of those weird things

Comment: result from SQL query is OK?.. where is the problem? in SQL or Java list?

Comment: but wait. i'm seeing that he is using a map implementation. maybe thats the reason

Comment: `player_list.put` sounds like you use a map to store the result, not a list, a map does not (most of the time) have an order.

Comment: @luk2302 exactly

Comment: @Alan you nailed it man. That seems to be the problem

Comment: the KEY (pun intended) question is, can we find a way of doing this while keeping his map implementation? because chaning everything to a list type could mess his entire code up (depending on the actual situation of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `player_list` you are using is quite obviously not a `List`. With the `put()` method and two arguments, it looks like a `Map`.

If what you use is a `HashMap`, no wonder the order is arbitrary - `HashMap` does not retain any kind of ordering.

You might want a `LinkedHashMap`, or another data structure altogether, like a custom object that you then actually store in a list, not in a map.

Comment: The original asker would like to comment:  It works perfectly with a LinkedHashMap! Subject solved!

Answer (score 1):

Is player_list a hashmap object? Hashmap does'nt maintain the order of the values inserted.Instead try using LinkedHashMap or TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the player_list which is a non-sorted map implementation. If you want to preserve the order of inserts in the map, use LinkedHashMap.